# Split string by spaces into array, except when part is quoted, with exceptions in golang

Tags: regex, go, split

Currently, I have the following code:

```
cmd := "echo \"Hello world\"!\x00"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)`)
args := re.FindAllString(cmd, -1)
fmt.Println("%v", args)
```

This yields the array `%v [echo "Hello world" !]`, but I want the output to be `%v [echo "Hello world"!]` (basically, quotes should contain everything inside of them as one item in the array, but the terminating quote should not signal the immediate start of the next item in the array).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Clarification. Is there a specific reason for the last group where you explicitly match any char but `'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly matching `"`, then any number of `^"`, then `"`, so of course it terminates after the second `"`. If you were to wrap that with `[^\s"']*` (matching anything but whitespace and `"`) in a grouping, I think it may give you what you are looking for. Let me know if this result is satisfactory.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[^\s"']+|([^\s"']*"([^"]*)"[^\s"']*)+|'([^']*)`)
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/fWWsx7dIIRd

I'm not super well versed as to regular expression efficiency, so pardon if this adds too much complexity to the expression.

EDIT: One caveat to this specific expression is that a single `"` will break something into two results, e.g. `hi"there` would split into `hi` and `there`.

Comment: This adequately does the trick; the caveat is fine for my purposes. Thanks for your help! Will mark as answer, but still keeping an eye out in case anyone else cooks up a juicy regex.

Comment: @CalebXu a good idea when regular expressions are involved. There are tons of ways to do it, and not all of them are optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Improved regex. This just matches quoted segments or non-whitespace segments. Can handle errant single quotes.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    cmd := "echo \"Hello world\"!\x00"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`("[^"]+?"\S*|\S+)`)
    args := re.FindAllString(cmd, -1)
    fmt.Println("%v", args)
    fmt.Println("%v", len(args))
}
```

Comment: This solution is cleaner, but also has a caveat (sorry to nitpick). The value `"first quoted""second quoted"` will be split into `"first quoted""second` and `quoted"`. This is probably an outlier that can be ignored, but one might expect it to end up in the same result given the quote is terminated then a new one opened (and subsequently terminated). I'd go with this answer if that is acceptable though.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear great point. I'll hold off on correcting anything as I agree it's down to the desired implementation. I certainly agree about the caveat.